# Dynamic JObject - parse invalid JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Consider I have following json:

```
{ "version": "1.0" }
```

I can parse it to dynamic JObject and use:

```
dynamic result = JObject.Parse(myJson);
string verison = result.Version; //works <3
```

But server returns the following json

```
{ { "version": "1.0" } }
```

This json is consider as valid by newtonsoft, but cannot access version anymore:

```
dynamic result = JObject.Parse(myJson);
string verison = result.Version; //error
```

How to access `Version` when onlt dynamic `result` is avalable?

Comment: { { "version": "1.0" } } is not valid JSON.

Comment: Hmm that is what I get from server. Maybe should I manually remove additional braces?

Comment: For me,  Newtonsoft throws an exception parsing that JSON starting with `{{`.

Comment: Hmm strange. I'll revalidate my code.

Comment: Try Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject instead - I am not familiar with JObject.  I would expect an exception.

Comment: Is the server in your control, or is it a third party API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `{ { "version": "1.0" } }` This json is consider as valid by newtonsoft

That is incorrect, you will not be able to parse this and will receive a exception of type `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException` (with: Invalid property identifier character: {. Path '', line 1, position 2.)

---

Invalid JSON:

```
{ { "version": "1.0" } }
```

Valid JSON:

```
{ "version": "1.0" }
```

*(In case you have server control, I suggest you make the necessary steps on the server to return valid JSON)*

However, worst case scenario, you could make this invalid JSON valid by removing the first char `{` and last char `}` before parsing it. For example like so:

```
 var myJson = json.Substring(1, json.Length - 2);

 dynamic result = JObject.Parse(myJson);
 string version = result.version;
```

Where `json` here was the original response containing the invalid JSON.

---

*Also note that for the JSON you provided you must use lowercase `version` as `result.version`. The dynamic property name must match **exactly** the one in the JSON*

Answer (score -1):

I think you trouble in capital "V" in "Version". Should be "result.version"

Comment: Read the very first part of his question where he indicates that `result.Version` works just fine for the valid JSON.

Comment: it can be just a typo